# Fixed top row of a table

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, sass

Position fixed does not help in here may be I am doing something wrong.

The input boxes in the first row should remain frozen on scroll. I know this has been answered before but none of the solutions is working.

http://jsfiddle.net/roshanjsachan/r8WDb/

```
.table{
text-align:center;
overflow: auto;
    table{
        width: 95%;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 5px;
         }
    }
.table_scroll
 {
display:block;
height:500px;
overflow-y:scroll;
 }

<div class="table">
<table class="table_scroll">
<tbody>
<tr class="main_tr">
 <th class="input_col"><input title="empno" placeholder="empno" type="text" class="col_data" id="empno" autocomplete="off"></th>
 <th class="input_col"><input title="name" placeholder="name" type="text" class="col_data" id="name" autocomplete="off"></th>
 <th class="input_col"><input title="job" placeholder="job" type="text" class="col_data" id="job" autocomplete="off"></th>
 <th class="input_col"><input title="boss" placeholder="boss" type="text" class="col_data" id="boss" autocomplete="off"></th>
 <th class="input_col"><input title="hiredate" placeholder="hiredate" type="text" class="col_data" id="hiredate" autocomplete="off"></th>
 <th class="input_col"><input title="salary" placeholder="salary" type="text" class="col_data" id="salary" autocomplete="off"></th>
 <th class="input_col"><input title="comm" placeholder="comm" type="text" class="col_data" id="comm" autocomplete="off"></th>
 <th class="input_col"><input title="deptno" placeholder="deptno" type="text" class="col_data" id="deptno" autocomplete="off"></th>
</tr>

<tr id="row1" class="remove table_row">
  <td>7369</td>
  <td>SMITH</td>
  <td>CLERK</td>
  <td>7902</td>
  <td>1980-12-17</td>
  <td>800.00</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>20</td>
</tr>
<tr id="row2" class="remove table_row">
  <td>7370</td>
  <td>ALLEN</td>
  <td>CLERK</td>
  <td>7902</td>
  <td>1980-12-17</td>
  <td>800.00</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>20</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/r8WDb/3/

Comment: Your CSS markup is wrong. You can't nest your CSS (`.table { .. table { .. } .. }`)

Comment: row with class main_tr goes outside table.@Pete

Comment: I forgot to mention i am using scss for styling.So my markup is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This answer only applies to vertical scrolling and assumes the table will fit horizontally. If you need horizontal scrolling you'll need to do more jQuery to listen to the scroll events and update styles.

**Issue 1: Column widths change**

Option 1: In CSS set table-layout:fixed and predefine the widths of each column.

Option 2: Measure the columns with jQuery and then apply table-layout:fixed and set the width of each column.

```
var $table = $('table');
var $tbody = $table.find('tbody');
var $ths = $table.find('th');
var $tds =  $table.find('tbody tr:first-child td'); //only need the first row
var widths = [];


//Measure the widths
$ths.each(function(i, cell) {
    var $cell = $(cell);
    widths.push(
        cell.clientWidth //don't use jquery's width() it's inaccurate in cases with bordercollapse.
        - parseFloat($cell.css('padding-right'))
        - parseFloat($cell.css('padding-left'))
    );
});

//Freeze the cells widths
$ths.each(function(i, cell) {
    $(cell).width(widths[i]);
});
$tds.each(function(i, cell) {
    $(cell).width(widths[i]);
});
```

**Issue 2: Scrolling**

Option 1: Set the table, tbody and thead to display:block. Set thead to position:absolute. Set the tbody to scroll.

```
table.freeze  {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

table.freeze thead {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    display:block;
    background-color:#fff;
}
table.freeze tbody {
    height:200px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hide;
    display:block;
}
```

Option 2: Clone the thead into a separate table. Position that table absolutely within another wrapper. This approach may make other behaviors easier, such as the head on page scroll or adding horizontal scrolling.

**Fiddle**
Here's a working example. Note, you'll need to ensure the result pane is wide enough to view the entire table.

http://jsfiddle.net/shindigg/232Vv/1/

Answer (score 1):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/232Vv/)
You have to add

```
tr.table_row td {
    display:table-cell;   
}
```

Comment: Though not working perfectly.It has given me a correct path to carry on.Good answer.@saranya

Answer (score 0):

Try change you css:

```
.table_scroll
 {
display:block;
height:500px;
overflow-y:auto;
 }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r8WDb/6/

Comment: What are u trying to say sir.I already have that in code.@nitin

Comment: make overflow-y: auto